# no. of ordered triples of $(x,y,z)$ such that $\bf{L.C.M}(x,y,z) = 243$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> If $x,y,z\;,$ Then the no. of ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $\bf{L.C.M}(x,y,z) = 243$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $x=3^p$ and $y=3^q$ and $z=3^r\;,$ where $p,q,r\geq 0$ and $p,q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$

So $\bf{L.C.M(3^p,3^q,3^r)} = 3^5$ means $\bf{max.(p,q,r)}=5$

Now how can i solve after that, Help me

thanks

Comment: $$\big\{ (p,q,r) : \max(p,q,r) = 5 \big\}
= \big\{ (p,q,r) : p, q, r \le 5 \big\}
\setminus \big\{ (p,q,r) : p, q, r < 5 \big\}\\
\implies \#\big\{ (p,q,r) : \max(p,q,r) = 5 \big\} = 6^3 - 5^3 = 91
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

The number of ordered triples $(x, y, z)$ of positive integers with least common multiple $243 = 3^5$ is the number of ordered triples of the form $(3^p, 3^q, 3^r)$, with $0 \leq p, q, r \leq 5$ in which at least one of $p, q, r$ is equal to $5$.

There is exactly one triple with $p = q = r = 5$.

If exactly two of $p, q, r$ are equal to $5$, then the third exponent is one of the five numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.  Thus, the number of triples in which exactly two of $p, q, r$ are equal to $5$ is

$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5 = 3 \cdot 5 = 15$$

If exactly one of $p, q, r$ is equal to $5$, then each of the other exponents is one of the five numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.  Thus, the number of triples in which exactly one of $p, q, r$ is equal to $5$ is

$$\binom{3}{1} \cdot 5^2 = 3 \cdot 25 = 75$$

Hence, the total number of ordered triples of positive integers with least common multiple $243$ is

$$\binom{3}{3} \cdot 5^0 + \binom{3}{2} \cdot 5^1 + \binom{3}{1} \cdot 5^2 = 1 + 15 + 75 = 91$$

A simpler approach is to observe that since $p, q, r \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, there are precisely $6^3 = 216$ ordered triples of the form $(3^p, 3^q, 3^r)$.  Of these, there are $5^3 = 125$ ordered triples in which $p, q, r \neq 5$.  Hence, there are

$$6^3 - 5^3 = 216 - 125 = 91$$

ordered triples in which at least one of $p, q, r$ is equal to $5$.

Answer (score 2):

As you have $\max(p,q,r) = 5$. Without loss of generality, lets assume $p$ is the maximum. In which case, we have $q,r$ can be any value in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Hence, there are $36$ possible unordered triplets. To get the number of ordered triplets, multiply the above number $36$ by $3!$ to get $216$ ordered triplets.